# Agenda/Session Scheduler (to automatically assign timeslots)

Tags: gratis, scheduling, optimization

I am looking for an optimization tool that can schedule sessions with assigned participants in such a way that participants can attend all of their assigned sessions (i.e. no participant would have to decide between two simultaneous sessions they are assigned to).

The license must allow to use the tool free of charge in a work environment.

In particular, I would like the tool to respect the following constraints:

- A list of sessions.
- A list of mandatory and optional participants for each session.
- A list of days and allowable time ranges on each day.
- Restrictions to the relative order of sessions (i.e. the requirement that a certain session take place before another session).
- Optionally, additional day and time restrictions per participant.

---

**Sample input:**

Sessions:

- Session 1: 1 hour, requires P1, P2, optional P3
- Session 2: 2.5 hours, requires P4, P5
- Session 3: 1 hour, requires P2, P4

Schedule between Monday and Tuesday, between 10 am. and 6 pm. with a break from 1 pm. to 2 pm.

**Sample output:**

- Session 1: Monday, 10 am. to 11 am.
- Session 2: Monday, 10 am. to 12:30 am.
- Session 3: Monday, 1 pm. to 2 pm.